# Background of TextSpan has different height if TextSpan contains different language

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

The background of textspan in SelectableText.rich or RichText has different height if there are diffenrnt languages (like chinese and english).

```
return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        body: Center(
            child: RichText(
          text: TextSpan(
            text: 'english中文',
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.red,
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 18.0),
          ),
        )));
```

[image]

The following solution is not work because TextSpan do not have property strutStyle.
https://medium.com/@najeira/control-text-height-using-strutstyle-4b9b5151668b

please help to solve this problem.
thanks.

Comment: You can use `children:` property which is take TextSpan list and set here your seccond language and give a size smaller than english

Answer (score 0):

What I do in this case, at least within a text span widget, is play around with the "height" attribute in the text style. I change the shorter text element's height to be closer to the taller one.